# Magento 2.3 - How to add custom column to customer_entity table

Tags: customer-attribute, declarative-schema

I'm creating a Referral Program module, and I want to create a custom column inside the `customer_entity` table. The column is `referred_by` and it's a foreign key that as a relation with the `customer_entity` table itself. This column contains the id of the customer that sent the `referral_code`. How can I implement this? How can I add this field inside the `customer_entity` table? I try to add an attribute as `static` type, but the new column doesn't appear inside that table. I need to declere the db_schema.xml?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try using following code.

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerEdit/registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_CustomerEdit',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerEdit/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_CustomerEdit" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerEdit/etc/db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="customer_entity">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="referred_by" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false"
                comment="Referred By"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="CUSTOMER_ENTITY_REFERRED_BY_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" table="customer_entity"
                    column="referred_by" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Then run following command to generate `db_schema_whitelist.json`

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name Anshu_CustomerEdit
```

Then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

Here `Anshu` is the module namespace and `CustomerEdit` is the module name.

You can modify code according to your requirement.

Comment: How do you set value to this field @AnushuMishra

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran This will just add the field in the table. To add the content in the field Data Patch needs to be created. You can read about them at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html

Comment: @AnshuMishra this is adding new field in the table, but not able to show the fields in the customer edit and admin edit pages. How to implement that ?

Comment: @santhoshnsscoe you need to add customer attribute using data patch.

Comment: @AnshuMishra yeah, added to used_in_forms using the patch. My attribute is textarea. I am getting this error in the admin. The "formElement" configuration parameter is required for the "custom" field.

Comment: @santhoshnsscoe you need to add 'formElement' attribute to in the configuration. 'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Textarea::NAME,

Comment: @AnshuMishra now the fields are coming in admin, but they are not saving to db. Also, in frontend `$block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('bio');` is not working.

Comment: @santhoshnsscoe How did you verify that data is not saved in the db? For frontend, you need to use $block->getCustomer()->getBio() to get the value.

Comment: @AnshuMishra got it, the problem was not adding this `'user_defined' => true,` while creating the attribute. Now working fine. $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('bio')->getValue() works now.

Comment: @AnshuMishra thanks its works for me , if anyone need help https://github.com/bdcrops/module-declarative#how-do-you-modify-a-table-added-by-another-module

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InstallSchema` Script to do that. Kindly refer below code:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('customer_entity')
            )->addColumn(
            'referred_by',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => true],
            'Referred By'
            )->setComment("Id of the customer that sent the Referral code");

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, and then how can I add the field inside the entity model of customer? Because this field then I need to get and set

Comment: @magefms M2.3 should be added via declarative schema even though it acepts, correct me if am wrong

Comment: @MirkoRapisarda Try with customer attribute for your requirement you can't do this via custom field in a table.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, yeah you are right but just giving him an easier way for now since it also works for 2.3.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran but with custom attribute, I lost the possibility to add a foreign key relationship, for this reason I want to add it as a real column

Answer (score 1):

Create new customer custom attribute for referral_code while installing referral module. here is a link to follow how to add custom attribute in customer section.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html

you can fetch custom attribute value from customer object using below code.

```
$customer->getCustomAttribute('FIELD_NAME')->getValue();
```

replace FIELD_NAME by your custom attribute name

Comment: but in this way I lost the possibility to add the `referenced_by` field as a foreign key