# Magento 2.3 - Add a new column after one column into the table using db schema

Tags: database, magento2.3, declarative-schema

**I need to add a new column after one of the particular columns in the existing table using DB schema & checked this dev doc [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html), they didn't mention about the before or after column.**

**Is there any way to do this?**

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251884/magento-2-3-how-to-implement-declarative-schema-in-custom-module

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266635/magento-2-3-how-to-add-custom-column-to-customer-entity-table

Comment: @HiteshBalpande I wish to add a new column, before or after the existing column in a table.
i.e. Let's say we have column_a, column_b, column_d in a table. 
Now I would like to add a new column (column_c) which should come after column_b.

Comment: @MohamedAsar, I am also looking for the same solution. I think this should be there in DB Schema. Unfortunately, I can't see it at anywhere. Hoping for some resolution in future.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution for this but it seems this wasn't implemented yet by the Core team https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: Tried putting the "after" attribute in the column and I'm getting the error:
`Element 'column', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 10

Verify the XML and try again.`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for the sake of others who find this looking for an answer - Do not do this unless you run on Mysql 8.0.29 or after, or another RDS which supports instant add (I'd generally just suggest not doing it at all, column order is often irrelevant). Be careful of things like Postgrel 10 vs 11 where in v10 if you use default NULL it isnt supported, but in v11 it is.

This is why Magento does not supply this functionality because it can have a severe impact on the next run of setup:upgrade or setup:db-schema:upgrade for versions of Mysql that come before this, or others RDS's that do not support ALGORITHM=instant for column adds or column adds with specific boundaries (such as using before/after, default null, etc).

In older version of MYSQL altering tables required locking the table and then implementing the change - the more rows you have the longer this process takes. I mostly see this implemented on the order grid to disastrous effect as they can often have 10s of millions of rows leading to a very long downtime, or if you use blue/green configuration it can lead to hampered site performance or loss of specific functionality for minutes to hours. (As a side note, dont add to core tables, use extension or map tables if necessary)

However if you wish to do this, which I suggest not as its mostly for vanity,  but if you still wish to go ahead then you can create it manually or use an UpgradeSchema with something like the below

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;


class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {
    
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        // Switch this for a version check and/or if columns exists check
        if (version_compare($context–>getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $connection = $setup–>getConnection();
            $connection–>addColumn(
                $setup–>getTable($targetTableName),
                $yourNewColumnName,
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'length' => 255,
                        'default' => '',
                        'comment' => $yourNewColumnDescription
                        'after'   => $yourTargetColumn
                    ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I highly suggest sticking to db-schema.xml to avoid the need for a migration set after this.