# Magento2 - Successfully add new column and field for registration. But where does the data save for new field?

Tags: magento2, customer, registration

I have successfully added new field for the registration form.

But the problem I'm facing right now is where does the data save? In which table in database?

I tried looking in the customer_entity but the data is not saved there. Any idea?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iOka.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]
And here's my code for the front end.

> Magento_Customer/templates/additional.phtml

```
<div class="field account_id required">
<label class="label" for="account_id">
  <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account ID')) ?></span>
</label>
<div class="control">
   <input type="text" name="account_id" id="account_id" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Account ID')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the type of your attribute is varchar you will find it in customer_entity_varchar.

As the attribute_id is 160 in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_entity_varchar WHERE `attribute_id` = 160
```

Comment: Thanks found it. Sorry just new to this magento 2. But how can I do it if I want the value to add in the customer_entity table? Is there any way to manipulate the code so that the value will be added in the customer_entity table?

Comment: This needs more coding. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266635/magento-2-3-how-to-add-custom-column-to-customer-entity-table for a up to date approach.

Comment: I see. Okay. Thanks